# Using traits with the same fileds name and declaration

Tags: scala, traits

I have abstract class Person and two traits Employee and Student

```
abstract class Person(val name: String) {
  val tax: Double
}

trait Employee {
  val salary: Double;
  lazy val tax: Double = salary * 0.1;
}

trait Student {
  val tax: Double = 0.0;
}
```

And i need to create 2 instances using these two traits

```
studentEmployee = new Person("John") with Student with Employee {override var salary: Double = 1000};
employeeStudent = new Person("Mike") with Employee with Student {override var salary: Double = 1000};
```

I get error:

> ...inherits conflicting members:   lazy value tax in trait Employee of type Double  and   value tax in trait Student of type Double ...

How can I use two traits with fields with the same name?

Comment: When you define an abstract method that returns a value, don't use `val`. Use  `def tax: Double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideal way is to create a separate Trait for tax called `Tax` and extend the `Employee` and `Student` from this Base trait. Traits ideally should act like an interface and should not have the actual implementation. The implementation should be part of the class that extends this traits.

The below implementation takes care of this

```
abstract class Person(val name: String) {
}

trait Tax {
    val tax: Double

}
trait Employee extends Tax {
  val salary : Double;
  override val tax : Double ;
}

trait Student extends Tax {
  override val tax : Double;
}

var studentEmployee = new Person("John") with Student with Employee {
                   override val salary: Double = 1000;
                   override val tax = salary * 0.1};


var employeeStudent = new Person("Mike") with Employee with Student {
                  override val salary: Double = 1000 ;
                  override val tax = 0.0};

scala> studentEmployee.tax
res42: Double = 100.0

scala> employeeStudent.tax
res43: Double = 0.0
```

Comment: I choose this with small modification. I'm still declaring tax value in Traits and don't override them while creating instance of object

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is here that you are trying to override `val` with `var` and the second problem is called diamond problem. The problem can be solved as follows:

```scala
abstract class Person(val name: String) {
  val tax: Double
}

trait Employee {
  var salary: Double
  val tax: Double = salary * 0.1
}

trait Student {
  val tax: Double = 0.0
}


val studentEmployee = new Person("John") with Student with Employee {
override val tax = 2.0
  override var salary: Double = 1000
}
val employeeStudent = new Person("Mike") with Employee with Student {
  override val tax = 2.0
  override var salary: Double = 1000
}
```

You can find here similar problem solution: http://eed3si9n.com/curious-case-of-putting-override-modifier

And you can read more about linearization here: http://eed3si9n.com/constraining-class-linearization-in-Scala
And here: https://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Comment: I'm writing on mobile phone couldn't hide links, will edit later

Comment: I believe in this case the tax value will remain as 2.0 in both `studentEmployee` and `employeeStudent`

Comment: This is just an example case how to eliminate the error, you can multiply salary value. However, if you want to have a dynamic result you can use a def/closure (method) for tax and you don't need to define the salary field as mutable variable

Comment: this overriding val with var it's just a typo here. Thanks for answer, but it's a problem with overriding tax, so i don't have a tax from trait.